# Refresh token for Google Storage Client

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

I must be stupid I think. Using `OAuth`.

Have the following piece of code

```
// Authenticate with Google            
        using (MemoryStream stream =
            new MemoryStream(GetSecrets()))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";
            this.userCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```

Works fine and sets `this.userCredential` as expected

Now I want to create a `StorageClient`

But `StorageClient` cannot be created directly from `UserCredential`.

The only way I can see is to create from the `AccessToken`

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(this.userCredential.Token.AccessToken);                                        
        return StorageClient.Create(googleCredential);
```

Problem is this token expires after an hour.

However, in C# I cannot for the life of me find a way to pass in the refresh token (which I have in the UserCredential) and have it refresh itself as needed

It seems possible in `Java` though, using the `.Builder`

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way of achieving this is to create the `StorageService` yourself, and then pass that to the `StorageClientImpl` constructor:

```
var service = new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
    ApplicationName = StorageClientImpl.ApplicationName,
});

StorageClient client = new StorageClientImpl(service);
```

We might consider adding an overload of `Create` that takes an `IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer` instead of a `GoogleCredential`, in the future.

Comment: If this works, thank you so much!!!! Seems wrong to mess with an Impl -- hope that won't break going forward.

But its way better than continually creating new clients with manually refreshed AccessTokens !

Comment: @NickAmbrose: No, the "Impl" class is part of the public API - we won't be breaking it. The separation between StorageClient and StorageClientImpl is primarily so that can write test doubles of StorageClient.

Comment: Jon -- I cannot thank you enough, this solved my problem perfectly! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond.